# General Ledger Account Code Format

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, accounting

I have added a general ledger account table to my database to store account codes and their descriptions.

I have asked three potential clients, two use a 4 digit numeric code the other a 3 digit numeric code.

I have been unsuccessful in finding any standards for the account code, can anyone recommend a format based on their experience with general ledger?

Numeric(4), Varchar(5) etc...

Comment: what makes you think there's a standard?  Who would publish this standard?  What country would it apply to?

Comment: It was a thought only, im bascially just asking advice from someone who has set this type of table up before.

Comment: @S.Lott,  That's a bit unfair - you misunderstood me, I said it was a thought that there may be a standard.  My question was NOT "does a standard exist?" it was "what column format should I be using to store account codes?"  That is a genuine question and not a random one.  I would still have asked the question if I knew there was no standard.  I needed advice from someone with experience - just like mwan below.  If not for the advice I got below, I would probably have used numeric(4), which was most likely a mistake in the long run.

Comment: Don't correct your question int the comments.  Actually **update** your question to be clear.  Don't explain or justify in a comment.  Actually make the question better.  Only you can clarify your question.  Please.  Clarify it.

Comment: I still don't see why you down voted me for a thought, but anyway updated as you requested.

Comment: -1: "based on their experience with general ledger?".  You have to actually look at the actual data you must actually store.  Our experience is useless.  What actual account numbers do you have to store?  Look at those.  Don't ask random strangers for their opinions.  What does your actual data actually look like?  Please be specific about your actual data.

Comment: That's nonsense, experience is not useless.  Why did you assume I have any data?  I don't. I am designing a system for multiple clients.  I simply know that in other systems similar to mine they allow you to put a general ledger account codes against parts received. That's all I want to do.

Comment: "I simply know that in other systems similar to mine they allow you to put a general ledger account codes against parts received".  And you have no sample data of any kind?  I'm truly and deeply amazed that you have no data.  I'm deeply sorry you have no example data.  Without example data, how will you write unit tests?  How can you be sure you've done the right thing?  How do you know it works? Your situation doesn't improve the question very much, however.  You're asking random strangers for a random number.

Comment: I don't have any sample data. I don't know anything about unit tests either, sorry but I'm not an experienced developer like yourself.   I think getting advice from someone experienced is much better than me plucking out a random number.  I don't like down votes and I want to improve and do things right by the forum.  I tried.  You only seem to want to criticise me so we are probably wasting each others time.

Comment: "advice from someone experienced is much better than me plucking out a random number."  False.  Your random number is exactly as good as our random numbers.  It really is.  Until you get sample data, you are doomed.  You are in a bad position.  I have sympathy.  But your bad position -- and a request for information that we cannot provide -- does not make this a good question.  Facts (and factual answers) make a good question.  This question can't help anyone else.  Only **you** can gather those facts.  That's why the downvote.  I'm telling you how to improve: **get facts**.

Comment: @S.Lott.  "Get facts." You make it sound oh so simple. As I have learnt there is no standard and no general rule. To be factual I would need to go to every single POTENTIAL client all round the world and ask what format their GL account code is.  Not possible. I have asked three potential clients, two use a 4 digit numeric code the other a 3 digit numeric code.  There you go sample data - you have it - now what? Do I use a 4 digit numeric format based on the sample data as you state? From mwan's experience most use between 4-8 characters and sometimes with non-numerics!!

Comment: "I have asked three potential clients"  Finally.  You have facts.  Please remove all the comments.  Please **update** the question to include your facts.

Comment: I have updated the question as you ask.  How do these "facts" help? To me they are of little relevance.  It is the many other potential clients I am concerned about.  What is your solution/suggestion - Numeric(4)? I do not want to remove the comments just yet.

Comment: If the comments are important, please **update** the question to contain the actual important part.  Moderators tend to delete long exchanges like this because they're confusing and add no value.  The **question** matters.  The comments don't matter.  "the many other potential clients I am concerned about"  Find a way to poll, ask, survey, study or otherwise discover this.  Don't ask random strangers.  Ask potential clients. Get facts.

Comment: I have updated the question.  These comments are valuable, if not at least interesting anyway.  "Our experience is useless."  I have never met anyone who appears to think experience is useless. I am going to go with VarChar(10).

Comment: If the comments are important, please **update** the question to contain the actual important part.  The comments do not get read.  People read the question and move on.  The question **must** be as complete as possible.  Please, please, please.  Actually **update** the question and remove the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard format. I've worked with upwards of 10 financial systems, all have used different GL code formats.

Have a look at the data being used currently and, if possible, check any restrictions imposed by the front-end software (ie numeric only, up to 10 characters long etc) and then set your field accordingly.

Anecdotally (just for reference) the systems I have dealt with have been (from memory) obviously unique, between 4 and 8 characters in length and only numeric - but that's certainly not a hard and fast rule. And I've always stored them as `varchar`s because often the front-ends allow non-numeric codes (even thought I've never come across them being used).

Comment: Thanks - appreciate your advice.  I don't have any specific data to look at as I am designing for systems used by multiple clients and I'm not aware of any restrictions accept that it must be unique.  Happy to go with varhchar.  So would you say 10 characters is a good starting point?

Comment: @Reafidy: From my experience, I'd say yes - but I wouldn't make the call without proper requirements if I were you.

Comment: thanks that's all I was after really, just advice from someone with experience, I have none with the accounting side of things and its a very very minor part of the application. I just had to start somewhere.

Comment: @Reafidy: No probs :) Good luck with it.

Comment: +1: "Have a look at the data being used currently".  The most sensible thing to say.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard format or length for Accounting Codes. The length depends on the number of accounts you want to have in your system.

One thing you can do, Assign the different series to different types of accounts.
ex. Asset NACs like 1XXX, Liability NACs 2XXX, Revenue NACs 3XXX, Expense NACs 4XXX to identify the account from initial number.